# how can i pass my variable to my modal?

Tags: php

I'm having a hard time on passing my variable to my modal.

I can't simply pass my `informant id` to my modal and I really would want to use it for my query as my base to search for or compare it.

I don't know how to pass it like the URL passing of variable using `GET` function and I'm really new to this and just wanted to try modal unlike creating a new page for a summary.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=deviceADMIN | Missing Person Tracking System-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>ADMIN | Missing Person Tracking System </title>
    <!-- Bootstrap Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <!-- FontAwesome Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- Morris Chart Styles-->
    <link href="assets/js/morris/morris-0.4.3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- Custom Styles-->
    <link href="assets/css/custom-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <!-- Google Fonts-->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default top-navbar" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> <strong>POLICE ADMIN </strong></a>
            </div>

           <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 min</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 min</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">

                        <li><a href="../login.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--/. NAV TOP  -->
        <nav class="navbar-default navbar-side" role="navigation">
        <div id="sideNav" href=""><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i></div>
            <div class="sidebar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="main-menu">

                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="mp.php"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Missing Person Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a  href="ca.php"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Create Account</a></span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Manage Services <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="news.php?page=1"> News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contacts.php"> Contacts</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="active-menu" href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Transactions <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                             <li>
                                <<a class="active-menu"  href="transac_pending.php"> Pending</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="transac_verified.php"> Verified</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="transac_reject.php"> Rejected</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="report.php"><i class="fa fa-file"></i> Reports </a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="logs.php"><i class="fa fa-history"></i> Audit Trail</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>
        <!-- /. NAV SIDE  -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" >
            <div id="page-inner">
             <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h1 class="page-header">
                            Transaction Requests
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                </div> 
                 <!-- /. ROW  -->

                <div class="row"> 

                <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb">

                            <li class="active">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> List of Transaction Requests
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                </div>        

                            <div class="panel-body"> 
                                <div class="column" >
                                <tr>    
                                    <td>
                                        <table class="table table-hover" border="2">
                                        <col width="5%"></col>
                                        <col width="15%"></col>
                                        <col width="10%"></col>
                                        <col width="10%"></col>
                                        <col width="10%"></col>
                                        <col width="15%"></col>
                                        <col width="15%"></col>
                                        <col width="10%"></col>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                        <center>
                                            <th><center>Informant Name</th>
                                            <th><center>Informant Address</th>
                                            <th><center>Informant Contact</th>
                                            <th><center>Informant Email</th>
                                            <th><center>Sighted Person</th>
                                            <th><center>Action</th>

                                        </center>

                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>

                                     <?php 

                include('mysql_connect.php');
                    $query="SELECT * from tbl_informant,tbl_missing_person where informant_status='Pending' and reported_id=mp_id";
                    $result=mysql_query($query);

                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
                <tr>    
                    <td><center><?php echo $row['informant_fname'].' '.$row['informant_lname'];?></center></td>
                    <td><center>
                    <?php echo $row['informant_address'];?></center></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['informant_contact']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['informant_email']?></td>
                    <td>
                        <img src="<?php echo $row['mp_image_location'].$row['mp_image']?>" height=100 width=100><br>
                        <?php echo $row['mp_fname'].' '.$row['mp_lname']?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php 

                        $id=$row['informant_id'];
                        $_SESSION['id']=$id;

                        echo "<center>
                                <button type='button'class='btn btn-primary btn-sm?id=".$id."' data-toggle='modal' title='Confirm'data-target='#ModalConfirm'>
                                Confirm</button>         


                                <button type='button'class='btn btn-danger btn-sm?id=".$id."' data-toggle='modal' title='Confirm'data-target='#ModalReject'>
                                Reject</button>

                            </center>"
                        ?>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
    <!-- Modal for REJECT-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalReject" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title"><b>Rejecting Request:</h4></b>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Reason/s: </p>
          <textarea cols="75" rows="5" placeholder="Enter reason here.." name="transac_reason"></textarea>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- Modal for CONFIRM-->
   <div class="modal fade" id="ModalConfirm" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure you want to confirm request? </p>
          <?php
            $modalquery="select * from tbl_informant,tbl_missing_person,tbl_contact_person
                         where concat(reported_id=mp_id && mp_id=cp_id)";
          ?>



        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Yes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

            </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
             <!-- /. PAGE INNER  -->
            </div>
         <!-- /. PAGE WRAPPER  -->
        </div>
     <!-- /. WRAPPER  -->
    <!-- JS Scripts-->
    <!-- jQuery Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Metis Menu Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
     <!-- Morris Chart Js -->
     <script src="assets/js/morris/raphael-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/morris/morris.js"></script>
      <!-- Custom Js -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom-scripts.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No one is going to look through all that code to try and find the relevant code. You need to strip away everything that's not a part of your issue. Only post the _relevant_ parts.

Comment: This is literally explained in the [bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-related-target).

Comment: _Don't_ use the _deprecated and insecure_ `mysql_*`-functions. They have been deprecated since PHP 5.5 (in 2013) and were completely removed in PHP 7 (in 2015). Use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: okay sir , im just pointing out here on how i could pass my variable to my modal just like using the url variable in where i could use get function.

Answer (score 0):

You can't execute a live mysql query like this to modify the table.

The best way for this is with ajax, you can catch the id if is on the table and use ajax to execute the mysql query.

I suggest you put the informant id in the value of a button in the table with a class:

```
<button class="id" data-target="modal" value="<?= $row['informant_id'] ?>"/>
```

and you can get the value of the button with a jquery event with this:

```
$(document).on("click", "id", function(){

var id = $(this).val();

console.log(id);

// and handle the value

});
```

this is one of many ways to pass the variable, if you just want to print it on the modal, create a tag with an id "example" `<h1 id="example"></h1>` inside the modal and execute this:

```
$(document).on("click", "id", function(){

    var id = $(this).val();

    console.log(id);

    // and handle the value

    $(".modal #example").text(id);

    });
```

Regards.